# Props in NuxtPage

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

Good day, I created a page that should change the title depends of the place where was call, and I have a question, I need to pass the title as a page prop, I tried to send that with $router.push({ path: '', params: { titlePage: 'Value' } }), and the option params, but in the page I can't see this prop, how can I send this value as prop to the page. Or I need to created an independent page? I'm new with nuxt and vue.

Thanks

I read some options on internet, one of those was send the value as a router param

Comment: Hi. You probably will not get much response, because there is not much information provided and much of what could be said can easily be found with a quick Google search. You might want to mention examples (code) of what you have tried. "I tried to send that with $router.push()". "Send it" how? What are the relevant parts of your code where you would expect the prop to show? Try thinking of it this way: "Would I be able to answer a similar question, if someone else asked it? What other information would I need to provide an answer?"

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to pass `props` to a page, when you need to fetch data to pages u can use composables like `useFetch` or `useAsyncdata`.

But for this question you can use the `useHead` to set your page titles:

`/pages/testTitle1.vue`

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  const title = ref('Your title for page 1')

  useHead({
    title
  })
</script>
```

`/pages/testTitle2.vue`

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  const title = ref('Your title for page 2')

  useHead({
    title
  })
</script>
```

If you need more info about `useHead` composable check this docs: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-head